# Updating value of Listview Item Android Firebase

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, onitemclicklistener

I'm a bit of a noob so go easy!
I want to be able to update the value of a string I have stored in Firebase. 
Im using an onItemClickListener so that when a particular item in the list view is clicked, it will update the value to the current value + "attending".

I know that in order to do this I must get the current value from the listview item and then use a setter to update it to the new value when the item has been clicked. I'm just unaware how to actually do this.

Thanks in advance.

```
    new Firebase("https://amber-fire-8056.firebaseio.com/")
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    adapter.add((String) dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue());
                }

                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    adapter.remove((String) dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue());
                }


                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    adapter.add((String) dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue());
                    System.out.println("Events Have Been Updated");
                }

                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                }
            });

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String val =(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


                    Toast.makeText(MainFBActivity.this, "Attending Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

Rather than try to wrangle the `ListView` and `Adapter` yourself, **[you should use FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)!**

FirebaseUI provides a class named `FirebaseListAdapter` that will handle the child events for you:

```
ListView messagesView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages_list);

Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/messages");

FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ref) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, ChatMessage chatMessage, int position) {
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(chatMessage.getName());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(chatMessage.getMessage());

    }
};
messagesView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The `FirebaseListAdapter` handles the child events behind the scenes and keeps an underlying array in sync with the remote changes. All you have to worry about is populating the view inside of `populateView`.

Comment: you probably should add how to now implement `onItemClick()`: `adapter.getRef(position).child("text").setValue("new text")`

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try that immediately.

Comment: How do I now implement the onItemClick()?